# How many factors does $10^n$ have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to workout a pattern, I am not sure if there's any:

If $n = 1$, $10^n$ has $4$ factors.

If $n = 2$, $10^n$ has $9$ factors.

$\ldots$

If $n = 5$, $10^n$ has $49$ factors.

For n = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, we have a sequence $(4, 9, 15, 25, 36, 49)$. I just don't see any pattern here. Should I keep going till I find one?

Comment: It's $16$ for $n = 3$, not $15$. That should look somewhat familiar then.

Comment: Hint: What is the prime factorization of $10^n$? Can you say anything about all possible factors of $10^n$, given this factorization?

Comment: Also, for $n=6$ there are $49$ factors not for $n=5$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $10^n = 5^n \times 2^n$. How many different combinations of $5$'s and $2$'s can we get?

Comment: We get $(n + 1)$ $5$s and $(n + 1)$ $2$s?

Comment: Not quite. In the factorisation of $10^n$, there will be $n$ 5s and $n$ 2s. We need to choose $k$ 5s and $j$ 2s to get a factor. How many ways are there of doing this?

Comment: I really don't know what's going on here. Could it be $(k + 1)$ $5$s and $(j + 1)$ $2$s?

Comment: @Mathmo123 - very simple solution... Nice!!!

Comment: @DirtySkank I'll give you a question, and then see if you can apply it to this: lets say I have two $n$-sided dice, one blue and one green, and I roll both of them. How many possible rolls are there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If
$$x=\prod\limits_{i=1}^np_i^{k_i}$$
where each $p_i$ is a distinct prime and each $k_i$ is a positive integer, then the number of factors of $x$ is

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(k_i+1).$$

[Here](http://mathschallenge.net/library/number/number_of_divisors) is an approach to a proof of this fact.

Comment: It looks like $5^n$ would have $(k_i + 1)$ factors. $2^n$ would have that many factors as well, except we can't use the variable $k$ anymore, so there are $(j_i + 1)$ factors for $2^n$. Then  $10^n$ has $(k_i + 1)(j_i + 1)$ factors. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#Multiplicative_functions
I found the first $3$ functions to be very useful in number theory and could be derived logically since $10^n$ has factors $1,2,2^2,\cdots,2^n,5,2\cdot5,2\cdot5^2,\cdots2\cdot5^n,2^2\cdot 5,2^2\cdot5^2\cdots$
And so on you get that there are $n+1$ factors for powers of $2$ including $2^0$ and also every of that $n+1$ number is multiplied by all powers of $5$ so it gives $(n+1)^2$

Comment: Is there same number of factors for both $5^n$ and $2^n$?

Comment: @DirtySkank Yes,the factors are $1,5,25,125\cdots 5^n$ and $1,2,4,8\cdots 2^n$ now you multiply the number of factors of both $2^n$ and $5^n$